# In a Quickly app, should code go in "myapp" or "myapp_lib"?

Tags: application-development, gtk, quickly

I've just started looking into Quickly and Ubuntu desktop/GTK dev, and I'm a bit confused by the organisation of the template that Quickly provides.

Specifically, I'm confused about two related points:

1. Why is the logic for a window or dialogue split between a file in the lib folder and another in the application folder?
   For instance, the default template creates a `Window.py` under the lib folder, and a `MyappWindow.py` under the application folder.
   It seems that all of the default logic is in the `Window.py` file, but the features being implemented in the tutorial (`$ quickly tutorial`) are written in `MyappWindow.py`.
   The confusion for me here might stem from inexperience with gtk.
2. In general, how should the code be split (for none UI elements). For instance, code to connect to a sqlite db, code to contact web services, other Ubuntu integration code eg dbus service, indicators etc.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should go in `myapp`, not `myapp_lib`.

See here for more information:

- [What are the different application directories in a quickly ubuntu-application template for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155175/what-are-the-different-application-directories-in-a-quickly-ubuntu-application-t)