# What are the different application directories in a quickly ubuntu-application template for?

Tags: application-development, quickly

When you create a new ubuntu-application with quickly you will notice that it creates a directory structure like this:

- **MyApp**/

  - setup.py
  - bin/
  - help/
  - tests/
  - setup.py
  - **MyApp**/
  - **MyApp_lib**/

What are each one for? and what should be placed in MyApp and MyApp_lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick summary:

- `setup.py` - this has some settings in it that you can configure for when you package and publish your app to a PPA. You can see them commented out in a new Quickly project.
- `bin/` - when you run `quickly run` it loads the application from here.
- `help/` - this contains your bundled help files. You can edit these for when the user clicks *Help -> Contents*.
- `tests/` - this is where you can unit tests to ensure your different functions are working as expected. You can create a test suite that could be automated (this is not always required for smaller apps, but recommended for any kind of semi-seriuous or more project).
- `MyApp` - this is where you edit your code. You spend most of your time editing the files in here.
- `MyApp_lib` - this contains some functions that are part of Quickly - if you need to create your own functions for how you access data in the project, you can add them here too.

You missed one off too:

- `data` - this is where you store data for your app such as your Glade files (in the `data/ui` dir) and your icons and images (which are in the `data/media` dir).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! Though, when you say: "MyApp_lib [...] if you need to create your own functions for how you access data in the project, you can add them here too.", **could you mention an example?**

Comment: As an example, in Ubuntu Accomplishments we do some custom work with where bits of the software is installed - this functionality relates to the project's structure, so we put those functions in there. Generally you won't need to touch the _lib directory.